# How To guarantee that the input of the smart contract is not manipulated?

Tags: asch-development, sidechain-technology, asch, decentralized-applications

Let's say that my DApp got the following (smart) contract:

```
module.exports = {
  winner: async function(value) {

    if (value===10) {

        } 
  } 
}
```

Now the Dapp user can do someting which invoke the contract with some `value` which can be `10` or not. The Dapp determines if `value` equals `10` or not. So far so good.

But now it seems that anyone with a valid secret (and some XAS send to the Dapps's side chain) can invoke the contract with a simple `PUT` request to `api/<dappId>//transactions/unsigned` with `value` set to whatever they want.

How to ensure that the value of `value` is set by the Dapp and can not be manipulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i do understand Asch DApps run on a express server, with the cors middleware enabled, which means that anyone can do a request (GET, POST, PUT, etc ) from anywhere.

So one can invoke your contract easily with a script like that shown below:

```
const axios = require('axios');
var fee = '10000000'
var data = {
        secret: "<your secret>",
    fee: fee,
         type: 1001, //the number for contractfile.function
         args: 1000 // a very high score
         }
axios.put('http://<domain>:4096/api/dapps/<dappid>/transactions/unsigned',data)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Due to the above it is not possible to guarantee that in input is not manipulated (send from outside the DApp). Also see: https://github.com/AschPlatform/asch/issues/228